# Problem adding sharepoint sandboxed solution using powershell

Tags: powershell, sandbox-solution

I have powershell script which will create the WebApplication and SiteCollection and upload the solution. Creation of WebApplication and SiteCollection for user X works fine but Add-SpUserSolution is failing with UnauthorizedAccessException. Powershell process is running with credentials of  user X where as logged in user is Y.

Both user X and Y are farm admin and site collection admin as well as System admin (Db admin too)

What is the possible reason for this exception ?

Regards
Jeez

Edit

As suggested by Anders i tried with start-process
by invoking SetUpSpApp.ps1 as below

```
ExecSetup.ps1 (Machine A)

       start-process powershell C:\SetUpSpApp.ps1 -Credential $USerXCred 


SetUpSpApp.ps1 (Machine A)

function SetUp()
{

#creation of WebApp using New-SPWebApplication goes here ...

$site = New-SPSite $Url -OwnerAlias $OwnerLogin -Name $Name -Template $Template -Language $Language


 #other stuff ..
}
```

i tried invoking ExecSetup.ps1 using invoke-command from machine B ( logged in user Y)

```
 invoke-command -ScriptBlock { C:\ExecSetup.ps1 } -Computer "hostname" -Credential $UserXscred
```

fails with Access denied exception

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock { C:\SetUp.ps1 } -Computer "hostname" -Credential $UserXscred
```

script executes but fails when control reaches the Command New-SPSite with exception User not found exception

Same thing happened when I tried invoking scripts using WMI

```
  ConnectionOptions options =
                new ConnectionOptions();

            options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            options.Username = "userX";
            options.Password = "passwd";
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            ManagementScope scope =
                new ManagementScope(
                "\\\\MacineA\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass
                (scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
           // inParams["CommandLine"] = @"powershell.exe c:\ExecSetup.ps1";
            inParams["CommandLine"] = 
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Creation of the process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
            uint pid = (uint) outParams["processId"];
```

Comment: You might want to check your event log and 14/LOGS folders to get more detailed information.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: @Jaap  here is the exception details Add-SPUserSolution : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At E:\Scripts\CreateWebAppAndCollection.psm1:216 char:33
+         $solution = Add-SPUserSolution <<<<  -LiteralPath $SolutionPath -Site $Url
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...AddUserSolution:SPCmdletAddUserSolution) [Add-SPUserSolu
   tion], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletAddUserSolution

Comment: If i login using user X's credential and run the same script everything works fine! but if login using  Y's credential and try to create WebApp, SiteCollection using X as WebApp owner then creation of WebApp and SiteCollection works fine but Addition of sandboxed solution is failing

Comment: Are you creating a new Content DB for your web app in the script? Wouldn't user Y need db level permissions on that content DB?

Comment: both X and Y have admin privileges

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that you also need membership of the SharePoint_Shell_Access role to use PowerShell cmdlets that interact with the content database. Use the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet to enable this.

Comment: Note that the user that can give **your** user the shell admin permissions to the specific content database need to be shell admin itself. A good bet is your install account. Also remember that the shell that is used to add your permissions must be run with administrative privileges if UAC is enabled

Comment: thanks for the response but use of Add-SPShellAdmin did not help, am getting the same exception

Comment: @Anders, UAC is disabled and both logged in user Y and user X running the scripts are system admin

Comment: yes systems admin, but I agree it is worth trying out assigning user Shell Access for the database. You can get the content databases in PowerShell using Get-SPContentDatabase: `Get-SPContentDatabase | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "WSS_Content"} | Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName yourdom\spadmin`

Answer (score 1):

How do you start the PowerShell session with another user? I have experienced issues, especially with UAC enabled if you use Run As Other User.

Try instead to use

```
start-process powershell -Credential yourdom\youruser
```

Or to run as administrator

```
start-process powershell -verb runAs
```

Yet another option is to use Start-Job to run code as another user inside your script. Example:

```
start-job -scriptblock {get-eventlog -log system} -credential yourdom\youruser
```

Note that if you need to use SharePoint cmdlets you will need to use -InitializationScript parameter to add the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell snapin:

```
$job = start-job -InitializationScript {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell} -ScriptBlock {Get-SPFarm} -Credential mydom\svcSPFarm
Receive-Job $job
```

The cool thing about scripting this is also that you can use it in shortcuts or inside PowerShell scripts.

More info on [Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx) and [Start-Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347692.aspx)

Comment: I am invoking powershell via WMI and UAC is disabled on the system. Start-Process worked fine, since am passing the credential when i create the powershell process using WMI is not that sufficient ? because powershell so created runs under the account X and I assumed it will have all privilege associated with X

Comment: could you update the question with the relevant code you use to spawn your PowerShell process? Both out of interest and so I could test if permissions are different

Comment: Its happening because the invoke-command executes under logged in user's credential ie., Y even though I am passing X's credential as argument to invoke-command (does the passed credential just used to connect to the system?). Is it possible to run invoke-command to execute under X's credential